# Block at 1 clone per person on Github

Tags: git, github, clone, pull

I would like to know how I can do to let someone clone my private repo once on Github but they cannot do it again.

The constraint is that it can always do pull to update.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you so much !

Comment: What if their repo becomes corrupted? What if they switch to a different hard drive?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You will have to ask for a key again

Comment: @Julian I'm selling a docker image and I don't want someone to be able to resell it behind. I am looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a deploy key and revoke it when it's not more usefull.

Deploy keys can be repo isolated

Comment: Can't I automate this after a clone?

Comment: I'm not Github professional but i don't see anything about "once use deploy key" in the documentation